# Burn the [goodapp] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [goodapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goodapp) tag has only two questions each with zero votes. The name of the tag is ambiguous, and therefore it is unlikely that someone can be a "[goodapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goodapp) expert". Let's burn it!

Looking at one of the questions, it seems that the tag might refer to something called goodapp. A search on google yielded nothing, though.

Comment: [Good for Enterprise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.good.android.gfe&hl=en) may be what it's referring to.  Perhaps that needs to be retagged to something specific. The other question (with naming conventions) seems to be overly broad to me.  Both questions have had the tag removed, and it'll get culled in a day.

Comment: Looks like it's already been nuked.